# How to programmatically check if row is deletable?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, plpgsql, sql-delete

Say we have a PostgreSQL table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE master (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
);
```

and many other tables referencing it with foreign keys:

```
CREATE TABLE other (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    id_master INT NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT other_id_master_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id_master)
                                    REFERENCES master (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

Is there a way to check (from within trigger function) if a master row is deletable without actually trying to delete it? The obvious way is to do a SELECT on all referencing tables one by one, but I would like to know if there is an easier way.

The *reason* I need this is that I have a table with hierarchical data in which any row can have child rows, and only child rows that are lowest in hierarchy can be referenced by other tables. So when a row is about to become a parent row, I need to check whether it is already referenced anywhere. If it is, it cannot become a parent row, and insertion of new child row is denied.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to delete the row and roll back the effects. You wouldn't want to do that in a trigger function because any exception cancels all persisted changes to the database. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)

> When an error is caught by an `EXCEPTION` clause, the local variables of
> the PL/pgSQL function remain as they were when the error occurred, **but
> all changes to persistent database state within the block are rolled back**.

**Bold** emphasis mine.

But you can wrap this into a separate block or a separate **plpgsql function** and catch the exception there to prevent the effect on the main (trigger) function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_can_del(_id int)
  RETURNS boolean AS 
$func$
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM master WHERE master_id = _id; -- DELETE is always rolled back

   IF NOT FOUND THEN
      RETURN NULL;                        -- ID not found, return NULL
   END IF;

   RAISE SQLSTATE 'MYERR';                -- If DELETE, raise custom exception

   EXCEPTION
   WHEN FOREIGN_KEY_VIOLATION THEN
      RETURN FALSE;
   WHEN SQLSTATE 'MYERR' THEN
      RETURN TRUE;
   -- other exceptions are propagated as usual
END  
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This returns `TRUE` / `FALSE` / `NULL` indicating that the row can be deleted / not be deleted / does not exist.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4550825a2291d1c60755ba81c906fbc6)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5effd/1)</sub>

One could easily make this function dynamic to test any table / column / value.

Since [PostgreSQL 9.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-EXCEPTION-DIAGNOSTICS) you can also report back which table was blocking.
[PostgreSQL 9.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-EXCEPTION-DIAGNOSTICS) or later offer more detailed information, yet.

### Generic function for arbitrary table, column and type

Why did [the attempt on a dynamic function](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ccad99/1) that you posted in the comments fail? [This quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) should give a clue:

> Note in particular that `EXECUTE` changes the output of `GET DIAGNOSTICS`, but does not change `FOUND`.

It works with **`GET DIAGNOSTICS`**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_can_del(_tbl regclass, _col text, _id int)
  RETURNS boolean AS 
$func$
DECLARE
   _ct int;                              -- to receive count of deleted rows
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('DELETE FROM %s WHERE %I = $1', _tbl, _col)
      USING _id;                         -- exception if other rows depend

   GET DIAGNOSTICS _ct = ROW_COUNT;

   IF _ct > 0 THEN
      RAISE SQLSTATE 'MYERR';            -- If DELETE, raise custom exception
   ELSE
      RETURN NULL;                       -- ID not found, return NULL
   END IF;

   EXCEPTION
   WHEN FOREIGN_KEY_VIOLATION THEN
      RETURN FALSE;
   WHEN SQLSTATE 'MYERR' THEN
      RETURN TRUE;
   -- other exceptions are propagated as usual
END  
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0edc0a18ccec19e38d3612e95c615b5c)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ef320/2)</sub>

While being at it, I made it *completely dynamic*, including the data type of the column (it has to match the given column, of course). I am using the [polymorphic type `anyelement`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC) for that purpose. See:

- [How to write a function that returns text or integer values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587735/how-to-write-a-function-that-returns-text-or-integer-values/17605114#17605114)

I also use `format()` and a parameter of type `regclass` to safeguard against SQLi. See:

- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49718/3684)

Comment: Another way would be to create SELECT statements dynamically from the catalog tables. Consider related answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783678/how-can-i-find-tables-which-reference-a-particular-row-via-a-foreign-key/11788849#11788849) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383810/find-referenced-fields-or-foreign-key-constraint/18385588#18385588).

Comment: @NiksaBaldun: Since the `DELETE` never goes through, it should fit the [requirements for the STABLE declaration](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html). But I don't see how you would gain anything from that. Basically it tells the query planner that it can re-use the result within a single query if a function is called multiple times. This type of function is probably only called once. For more questions please start another question.

Comment: Apparently, it cannot be declared STABLE even though all changes will be rolled back. PostgreSQL doesn't seem to allow any UPDATE or DELETE statements in STABLE functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that also with `Procedure`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure p_delable(_tbl text, _col text, _id int)
 AS  $$
DECLARE
   _ct bigint; 
   _exists boolean;                             -- to receive count of deleted rows
BEGIN
    _exists := (SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT FROM information_schema.tables 
        WHERE  table_schema = 'public' AND    table_name   = $1 ));
    IF _exists THEN
        EXECUTE format('DELETE FROM %s WHERE %I = $1', _tbl, _col)
            USING _id;                         -- exception if other rows depend
        GET DIAGNOSTICS _ct = ROW_COUNT;

        IF _ct > 0 THEN
            RAISE SQLSTATE 'MYERR';            -- If DELETE, raise custom exception
        ELSE
            RAISE NOTICE 'no records found. no records will be deleted';
        END IF;
    ELSE
        raise notice 'Input text is invalid table name.';
    END IF;
   EXCEPTION
   WHEN undefined_column then
      raise notice 'Input text is invalid column name.';
   WHEN undefined_table then
      raise notice 'Input text is invalid table name.';
   WHEN FOREIGN_KEY_VIOLATION THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'foreign key violation, cannot be deleted.';
   WHEN SQLSTATE 'MYERR' THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'rows % found and can be deleted.', _ct;
END  
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You can call it, also can validate your input.

```
call p_delable('parent_tree', 'parent_id',30);
```

Will get:

```
NOTICE:  no records found. no records will be deleted
```

Lets try an actual exist row.

```
call p_delable('parent_tree', 'parent_id',3);
```

It will return

```
NOTICE:  rows 1 found and can be deleted.
```

It can also check your input table name exists in `public` schema or not.

```
call p_delable('parent_tre', 'parent_id',3);
```

It will give you notice:

```
NOTICE:  Input text is invalid table name.
```