# FOR EACH STATEMENT trigger example in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, postgresql-triggers

I've been looking at the [documentation of postgresql triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html), but it seems to only show examples for row-level triggers, but I can't find an example for a statement-level trigger.

In particular, it is not quite clear how to iterate in the update/inserted rows in a single statement, since `NEW` is for a single record.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`OLD` and `NEW` are null or not defined in a statement-level trigger. [Per documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)

> `NEW`
>
> Data type `RECORD`; variable holding the new database row for `INSERT`/`UPDATE` operations in row-level triggers. **This variable is
> null in statement-level triggers** and for `DELETE` operations.

> `OLD`
>
> Data type RECORD; variable holding the old database row for `UPDATE`/`DELETE` operations in row-level triggers. **This variable is null in statement-level triggers** and for `INSERT` operations.

Bold emphasis mine.

Up to Postgres 10 this read slightly different, much to the same effect, though:

> ... This variable is **unassigned** in statement-level triggers. ...

While those record variables are still of no use for statement level triggers, a new feature very much is:

#### Transition tables in Postgres 10+

Postgres 10 introduced transition tables. Those allow access to the whole set of affected rows. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-AUDIT-TRANSITION-EXAMPLE)

> **`AFTER`** triggers can also make use of *transition tables* to inspect the entire set of rows changed by the triggering statement.
> The `CREATE TRIGGER` command assigns names to one or both transition
> tables, and then the function can refer to those names as though they
> were read-only temporary tables. [Example 43.7](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-AUDIT-TRANSITION-EXAMPLE) shows an example.

Follow the link to the manual for code examples.

#### Example statement-level trigger *without transition tables*

Before the advent of transition tables, those were even less common. A useful example is to send [notifications](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html) after certain DML commands.
Here is a basic version of what I use:

```
-- Generic trigger function, can be used for multiple triggers:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_notify_after()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   PERFORM pg_notify(TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_OP);
   RETURN NULL;
END
$func$;

-- Trigger
CREATE TRIGGER notify_after
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON my_tbl
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_notify_after();
```

For Postgres 11 or later use the equivalent, less confusing syntax:

```
...
EXECUTE FUNCTION trg_notify_after();
```

See:

- [Trigger function does not exist, but I am pretty sure it does](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/255319/3684)

Comment: I was hoping that the statement-trigger had some *equivalent* of `NEW`  and `OLD` for the multiple-record case, and some way to iterate over those..

Comment: That's really too bad, because it means you can only do RBAR operations in triggers.

Comment: It appears that statement trigger is executed also if there are no rows affected. I don't need to analyze data inside, but I would like to know if there was any record updated. Any way to do it?

Comment: @user1038334: Instead of a trigger, you could encapsulate the query in a function and check results. Details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19393268/939860

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I think this has changed in newer versions... I believe there are now NEW and OLD tables accessible inside statement level triggers

Comment: @user1760150: True, a game-changer for this old question. I updated.

Answer (score 10):

Well, here are some examples of statement-level triggers.

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE public.test (
    number integer NOT NULL,
    text   character varying(50)
);
```

**Trigger function:**
`OLD` and `NEW` are still `NULL`
The return value can also be always left `NULL`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.tr_test_for_each_statement()
   RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    x_rec record;
BEGIN
    raise notice '=operation: % =', TG_OP;
    IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE' OR TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
        FOR x_rec IN SELECT * FROM old_table LOOP
            raise notice 'OLD: %', x_rec;
        END loop;
    END IF;
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT' OR TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
        FOR x_rec IN SELECT * FROM new_table LOOP
            raise notice 'NEW: %', x_rec;
        END loop;
    END IF;

    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$;
```

**Settings statement-level triggers** 
Only `AFTER` and only one event is supported.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_test_for_each_statement_insert
   AFTER INSERT ON public.test
   REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS new_table
   FOR EACH STATEMENT
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.tr_test_for_each_statement();

CREATE TRIGGER tr_test_for_each_statement_update
   AFTER UPDATE ON public.test
   REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS new_table OLD TABLE AS old_table
   FOR EACH STATEMENT
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.tr_test_for_each_statement();

CREATE TRIGGER tr_test_for_each_statement_delete
   AFTER DELETE ON public.test
   REFERENCING OLD TABLE AS old_table
   FOR EACH STATEMENT
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.tr_test_for_each_statement();
```

**Examples:**

```
INSERT INTO public.test(number, text) VALUES (1, 'a');
```

> =operation: INSERT = 
> NEW: (1,a)

```
INSERT INTO public.test(number, text) VALUES (2, 'b'),  (3, 'b');
```

> =operation: INSERT = 
> NEW: (2,b) 
> NEW: (3,b)

```
UPDATE public.test SET number = number + 1 WHERE text = 'a';
```

> =operation: UPDATE = 
> OLD: (1,a) 
> NEW: (2,a)

```
UPDATE public.test SET number = number + 10 WHERE text = 'b';
```

> =operation: UPDATE = 
> OLD: (2,b) 
> OLD: (3,b) 
> NEW: (12,b) 
> NEW: (13,b)

```
DELETE FROM public.test;
```

> =operation: DELETE = 
> OLD: (2,a) 
> OLD: (12,b) 
> OLD: (13,b)

Answer (score -1):

For example, you create `person` table as shown below.

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(20),
  age INTEGER
);
```

Then, you can create `my_func()` trigger function which can check if `NEW` or `OLD` has a record or `NULL` with [RAISE statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS trigger
AS $$
BEGIN
  RAISE INFO 'NEW:%, OLD:%', NEW, OLD;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Finally, you can create `my_t` trigger which runs `my_func()` before `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` or `TRUNCATE` operation happens on `person` table for each statement as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER my_t BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE OR TRUNCATE ON person
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION my_func();
```

*Memos:

- Whether or not `my_func()` returns `NULL` or returns `NEW` or `OLD` which has a record and if you set `BEFORE` with `FOR EACH STATEMENT` to a trigger, the operation `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` or `TRUNCATE` works with the actual record which you input without any modification. *Initially, `NULL` or a record is passed to `NEW` or `OLD`.
- In only case you set `BEFORE` and `FOR EACH ROW` to a trigger, you can change the actual record which you input with `INSERT` or `UPDATE` by returning `NEW` or `OLD` which has a record. *Initially, `NULL` or a record is passed to `NEW` or `OLD`.