# How to use a custom function as column default in a PostgreSQL table

Tags: database, postgresql

I created a table named `Loan` that contains the following columns:

```sql
loanID SERIAL, 
annualInterestRate INT, 
numberOfYears INT, 
loanAmount NUMERIC, 
monthlyPayment NUMERIC
```

The calculation of the `monthlyPayment` depends on `numberOfYears`, `loanAmount`, and the `annualInterestRate` as per the following formula:

```
monthlyPayment = (loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate) /
                (1 - (1/Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate , numberOfYears * 12) ));
```

I made a function named `get_monthly_payment()` that returns the `monthlyPayment` with no problem. For each row, I want to make the return of this function the default of the column `monthlyPayment`.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want the return value as *default* (allowing manual changes) or as *generated column* (no manual changes).

Comment: Where are `monthlyInterestRate` and `Math.pow` defined?

Comment: NO manual changes. By `Math.pow` I mean the power function, it`s just a java function. `monthlyInterestRate` is a custom function. @ErwinBrandstetter

Comment: Well unless you are using pl/java that is not going to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `monthlyPayment` is fixed as per your definition, hence completely functionally dependent, then consider not persisting the value *at all*. Keep using your cheap (!) function instead. Much cleaner and cheaper overall. Like:

```
SELECT *, f_monthly_payment(l) AS monthly_payment
FROM loan l;
```

Assuming the function is defined as `f_monthly_payment(loan)` (taking the row type of the table as argument). Else adapt accordingly.

Postgres 12 or later has `STORED` generated columns, but those only pay for expensive calculations. Persisted columns occupy space and slow down all operations on the table.

See:

- [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-columns-in-postgresql/8250729#8250729)

If you want to allow manual changes, a **column default** is the way to go (like you actually *asked*). But you cannot use your function because, [quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html):

> The `DEFAULT` clause assigns a default data value for the column whose
> column definition it appears within. The value is any variable-free
> expression (in particular, cross-references to other columns in the
> current table are not allowed).

The remaining solution for this is a trigger `BEFORE INSERT` on the table like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_loan_default_rate()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   NEW.monthlyPayment := (NEW.loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate())
                    / (1 - (1/power(1 + monthlyInterestRate(), NEW.numberOfYears * 12)));

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;

CREATE TRIGGER loan_default_rate
BEFORE INSERT ON loan
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION trg_loan_default_rate();
```

Assuming `monthlyInterestRate()` is a custom function.
And I replaced `Math.pow` with the built-in [Postgres function `power()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE).

`NEW` is a special record variable in trigger functions, referring to the newly inserted row. See:

- [FOR EACH STATEMENT trigger example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193567/for-each-statement-trigger-example/24195624#24195624)

`EXECUTE FUNCTION` requires Postgres 11. See:

- [Trigger function does not exist, but I am pretty sure it does](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/255319/3684)

Related:

- [PostgreSQL - set a default cell value according to another cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737738/postgresql-set-a-default-cell-value-according-to-another-cell-value/16754952#16754952)

Aside: consider legal, lower-case, unquoted identifiers in Postgres. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Comment: It seems from your code that we do not put the `NEW` operator before the custom function in the creation of the trigger. Just put it before the attributes of the column. Is that ok?. Another question is that: If the monthlyInterestRate() has parameters, shall we use the `NEW` operator before the parameters as well?.

Comment: @HusseinEid: `NEW` is a special record variable in trigger functions, referring to the newly inserted row. I added a link above.

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres 12+ you have generated columns:

A generated column is a special column that is always computed from other columns.

"A generated column is a special column that is always computed from other columns. ..."

So:

```
monthlyPayment numeric GENERATED ALWAYS AS(loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate) /
                (1 - (1/Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate , numberOfYears * 12) ))  STORED
```

Before version 12 you have to use `CREATE TRIGGER` to add a trigger to the table that calls a function that contains the above equation and sets the column value.

Comment: This is so good. But `monthlyInterestRate` is not a column in the table, it is a custom function. Can we use a custome function in the `GENERATED ALWAYS` clause?.

Comment: A generated column is different on principal from a column with a trigger-generated default. The latter is a plain column allowing manual changes. Not possible with generated columns. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8250729/939860

Comment: @Hussein Eid  If ```monthlyInterestRate``` is a function I'm not seeing the function call. It looks like a variable/coulmn name to me.

Answer (score 0):

Monthly Interest rate may not be a column on your table, but the Annual rate is. But Annual to Monthly is a simple calculation. The following can be used for both v12 generated columns and prior versions using a trigger. Additionally it provides what could be a generally usefully Postgres function for monthly payment calculations. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a051f0bf0e2a544d98d76db6ab3ad2c8) for each.

```
create or replace 
function monthly_loan_payment 
       ( amount  numeric
       , apr     numeric
       , term    numeric
       )
  returns numeric
  language sql 
  immutable strict  
/*  Given a loan amount, the Annual Percent (Interest) Rate and term (in years) 
 *  compute the monthly payment to service the loan. 
 *  Note. Monthly payment calculates correctly, but due to the exact terms of loan
 *        and date of payment receipt adjustments for end of loan payment may be 
 *        required.  
 */ 
as $$   
  with monthly (mrate) as (values ( (apr/100.00) / 12.00 ) )
  select round((amount * mrate)  /(1.0 - (1.0/ ((1.0 +mrate)^( term * 12.00)) ))::numeric,2) 
     from monthly;
$$;
```