# NULL values for referential_constraints.unique_constraint_* columns in information schema

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, information-schema, database-metadata

In Postgres 10 I have declared the following:

```
create table test_abc (
    pk integer not null,
    id integer not NULL,
    id2 integer not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (pk)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_abc_ids ON test_abc(id,id2);
```

And then a second table with a FK referencing the first:

```
create table test_def (
    id integer not null,
    abc_id integer,
    abc_id2 integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (abc_id,abc_id2) references test_abc(id,id2)
);
```

Now consider the output of this query:

```
SELECT unique_constraint_catalog, unique_constraint_schema, unique_constraint_name
FROM   information_schema.referential_constraints r
WHERE  r.constraint_name = 'test_def_abc_id_fkey'
----------------------
NULL NULL NULL
```

All `unique_constraint_*` columns have a null value.

From the [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/infoschema-referential-constraints.html) it seems these meta columns should contain the

> name of the [object] that contains the unique or primary key constraint that the foreign key constraint references (always the current database)

**Question:**
I'm surely in the same database, and the unique index declared on `test_abc` table is a unique constraint (otherwise I wouldn't be able to declare the FK to begin with), so why are these columns empty?

I'm using the `referential_constraints` with some joins to get information about the columns referenced by my foreign keys, but this way I'm missing all those where the unique constraint is set with an index.

Comment: Just tested your setup in pg 12 and, to my surprise, it works. Even though [the manual clearly says otherwise](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK): `A foreign key must reference columns that either are a primary key or form a unique constraint.` Seems like you are on to something ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Test setup

You assume the constraint name `test_def_abc_id_fkey`, the default name resulting from your setup in Postgres 11 or older. Worth noting, though, that default names have been improved for Postgres 12, where the same setup results in `test_def_abc_id_abc_id2_fkey`. [The release notes for Postgres 12:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/release-12.html#id-1.11.6.7.5.5)

> - Use all key columns' names when selecting default constraint names for foreign keys (Peter Eisentraut)

> Previously, only the first column name was included in the constraint name, resulting in ambiguity for multi-column foreign keys.

See:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=999901d428ee4b21e561ca093685b500)*

So let's use the explicit name `test_def_abc_fkey` for the FK constraint to avoid confusion:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_abc (
  pk  int PRIMARY KEY
, id  int NOT NULL
, id2 int NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_abc_ids ON test_abc(id,id2);

CREATE TABLE test_def (
  id      int PRIMARY KEY
, abc_id  int
, abc_id2 int
, CONSTRAINT test_def_abc_fkey  -- !
     FOREIGN KEY (abc_id,abc_id2) REFERENCES test_abc(id,id2)
);
```

And that [works in Postgres 9.5 - Postgres 12](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=430ecd74a527947c691965d89361a717), [even in Postgres 9.3.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/260e4d)
(I had been under the wrong impression an actual *constraint* would be required.)

#### Answer

Your observation from querying the information schema holds:

```
SELECT *
FROM   information_schema.referential_constraints
WHERE  constraint_name = 'test_def_abc_fkey';  -- unequivocal name
```

We get a row, but the three fields `unique_constraint_catalog`, `unique_constraint_schema` and `unique_constraint_name` are `NULL`.

The explanation seems simple. Those columns describe, as the manual puts it:

> ... the unique or primary key constraint that the foreign key constraint references

But there is no [`UNIQUE` ***constraint***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS), just a [`UNIQUE` ***index***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-unique.html). A `UNIQUE` constraint is implemented using a `UNIQUE` index in Postgres. Constraints are defined by the SQL standard, indexes are implementation details. There are differences like the one you discovered. Related:

- [How does PostgreSQL enforce the UNIQUE constraint / what type of index does it use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066972/how-does-postgresql-enforce-the-unique-constraint-what-type-of-index-does-it-u/9067108#9067108)

The same test with an actual `UNIQUE` *constraint* shows data as expected:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e2f22f40a90ab3aa9be45ac09ba988a6)*

So this seems to make sense. Especially since the [information schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/information-schema.html) is also defined by the SQL standards committee and indexes are not standardized, only constraints. (No index information in information schema views.)

All clear? Not quite.

#### However

There is another information schema view [`key_column_usage`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-key-column-usage.html). Its last column is described as:

> `position_in_unique_constraint` ... For a foreign-key constraint, ordinal position of the referenced column within its unique **constraint** (count starts at 1); otherwise null

**Bold** emphasis mine. Here, the ordinal position of the column in the *index* is listed anyway:

```
SELECT *
FROM   information_schema.key_column_usage
WHERE  constraint_name = 'test_def_abc_fkey';
```

See:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=430ecd74a527947c691965d89361a717)*

Seems inconsistent.

What's worse, [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) claims that an actual `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint would be required for the creation of a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint:

> A foreign key must reference columns that either are a primary key or
> form a unique constraint. This means that the referenced columns
> always have an index (the one underlying the primary key or unique
> constraint); so checks on whether a referencing row has a match will
> be efficient.

Seems to be a **documentation bug**? If nobody can point out where I am going wrong here, I'll file a bug report.

Related:

- [Postgres unique constraint vs index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542794/postgres-unique-constraint-vs-index)

### Solution

> I'm using the `referential_constraints` with some joins to get information about the columns referenced by my foreign keys, but this way I'm missing all those where the unique constraint is set with an index.

In Postgres, the system catalog is the actual source of truth. See:

- [Information schema vs. system catalogs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/75124/3684)

So you could use something like this (like I also added in the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=430ecd74a527947c691965d89361a717) above):

```
SELECT c.conname
     , c.conrelid::regclass  AS fk_table, k1.fk_columns
     , c.confrelid::regclass AS ref_table, k2.ref_key_columns
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_constraint c
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT a.attname
      FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
           , unnest(c.conkey) WITH ORDINALITY AS k(attnum, ord)
      WHERE  a.attrelid = c.conrelid
      AND    a.attnum = k.attnum
      ORDER  BY k.ord
      ) AS fk_columns
   ) k1 ON true
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT a.attname
      FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
           , unnest(c.confkey) WITH ORDINALITY AS k(attnum, ord)
      WHERE  a.attrelid = c.confrelid
      AND    a.attnum = k.attnum
      ORDER  BY k.ord
      ) AS ref_key_columns
   ) k2 ON true
WHERE  conname = 'test_def_abc_fkey';
```

Returns:

```
conname           | fk_table | fk_columns       | ref_table | ref_key_columns
:---------------- | :------- | :--------------- | :-------- | :--------------
test_def_abc_fkey | test_def | {abc_id,abc_id2} | test_abc  | {id,id2}
```

Related:

- [Find the referenced table name using table, field and schema name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618312/find-the-referenced-table-name-using-table-field-and-schema-name/15625024#15625024)
- [Find referenced field(s) of foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383810/find-referenced-fields-of-foreign-key-constraint/18385588#18385588)
- [How can I find tables which reference a particular row via a foreign key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783678/how-can-i-find-tables-which-reference-a-particular-row-via-a-foreign-key/11788849#11788849)

Comment: I would call this a behaviour bug, not a documentation bug.