# How to check if field is a foreign key in a loaded table?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, postgresql

Here is my script for loading a table and displaying it in a HTML `table`.

```
$fields = $this->db->list_fields($tableName);

$fieldData = $this->db->field_data($tableName);


$this->db->from($tableName);
$this->db->order_by($fields[0], "asc");
$query = $this->db->get(); 
$table = $query->result();


$columnsQ = $this->db->query("select count(column_name) from information_schema.columns where table_name = '".$tableName."'");
$columns = $columnsQ->row();

foreach($table as $row) {

    echo "\t<tr class='value'>\n";
    $colNr = 1;

    foreach ($row as $tdVal) {

        $colNr0 = $colNr-1;
        $valType = $fieldData[$colNr0]->type;
        $isForeign; // how to get info?

        if($colNr==1) {
            echo "\t\t<td data-valType='$valType' class='id'>$tdVal</td>\n"; }
        else {
            echo "\t\t<td data-isForeign='$isForeign' data-valType='$valType' data-colNr='$colNr'>$tdVal</td>\n"; }

        $colNr++;
    }

} 


</table>";
```

What query should be under `$isForeign` to get info about whether the loaded value is a foreign key or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the answers posted on this question, you will need to just add the extra constraint you require for your specific column as you iterate your foreach

[Similar question and multiple answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152260/postgres-sql-to-list-table-foreign-keys/4701736#4701736)

Comment: I'm struggling to find any difference in the question