# Way to get all relations and tables between tables

Tags: postgresql

I am working about a very hudge PostgreSQL database.

The database have more hundred relations between table. But I want to link  two tables named "client" and "services" (in order to quering these tables) but I don't know what relations take to link them.

I can't install tools to do this. I can only use the command-line interface.

Are there a way to do that ?

**EDIT** : This question is not duplicate because I never ask the relation presents in a table. 
I want a way to **map** (get all tables) **between two tables**. These two tables don't have a common relation because **they are distant from many tables** in the database.

Comment: Did you tryed to search before ask the question ? Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1152321/1216680

Comment: Yes I found that but it's not that I want. Please consider that I searched before asking question. I you understood my question you know that I want a list of tables and relations between table. Not a list of foreign keys.

Comment: I want an equivalent of a map to chain tables.

Comment: It's pretty hard to understand what you're talking about when you describe it in such general terms. Are you asking about foreign keys? Can you provide a short example illustrating your problem?