# ERROR: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to delete a row in my table `re_users` and I am getting error below:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (5, null, 2014-09-05 06:53:47.804037, 2014-09-05 06:53:47.804037, null, _fetch_mails, minutes, null, Fetchmail Service, (), -1, 2014-09-05 06:53:47, 5, f, f, 5, fetchmail.server).
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "UPDATE ONLY "public"."ir_cron" SET "user_id" = NULL WHERE $1 OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) "user_id""
```

kindly suggest me, how do I resolve it.

Waiting for reply.

Thanks

Comment: Do delete a row you need to use a `delete` statement, not an `update` statement.

Comment: my delete statement is `delete from res_users where login = 'admin'` and login is my column name.

Comment: Do you have any foreign keys defined with `on delete update`?

Answer (score 1):

The table ir_cron contains a row with the user_id that you're trying to delete, you should first edit that row or delete it before deleting the row in re_users.

Answer (score 1):

This is postgres' way of telling you there's a foreign key relationship that needs to be deleted first. Once you delete the row in your linked table, then you'll be able to get past this error.

Related: [How to query a table for foreign keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1152321/5361412)