# How to set FK relationship to NULL in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key-relationship

How to set `FOREIGN KEY (packet_id) REFERENCES girvi_packet(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` to NULL ?

If parent get deleted `postgreSQL` raises error that parent is missing I want to suppress this behavior. This constraint is added by default by some 3rd part tool. But my use case demands otherwise.

Comment: And what behavior do you *want* ? Cascade, set NULL ?

Comment: @wildplasser [Here](https://github.com/Atomidata/django-audit-log/issues/23) due to this issue I want to suppress this behavior

Comment: I want to allow orphan children

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the foreign key is to prevent orphan children. The only way you can do is to delete the constrain

```
ALTER TABLE ... DROP CONSTRAINT ...
```

Comment: `egirvidb=# alter table girvi_transactionauditlogentry drop constraint girvi_transactionauditlog_packet_id_4b31e38d_fk_girvi_packet_id, add constraint girvi_t
ransactionauditlog_packet_id_4b31e38d_fk_girvi_packet_id foreign key (packet_id) references girvi_packet(id) on delete set null;`  Yes I altered the table now its working

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically get the all constraints and then run alter on them ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152260/postgres-sql-to-list-table-foreign-keys