# Get information about foreing key from PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152260/postgres-sql-to-list-table-foreign-keys?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) answer but the information is not complete.

I'm trying to get the information whether the foreign key is "MATCH FULL", "MATCH PARTIAL" or "MATCH SIMPLE".

Which table/field this information is stored?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column `pg_catalog.pg_constraint.confmatchtype` (in the table `pg_constraint` in the schema `pg_catalog`) has the information you're looking for. It's just one character:

- `'f'` for `MATCH FULL`
- `'s'` for `MATCH SIMPLE` and
- `'p'` for `MATCH PARTIAL`.

Foreign key constraints are the ones with `pg_catalog.pg_constraint.contype = 'f'` BTW. Only those have a `confmatchtype <> ' '` (for obvious reasons).

See also ["51.13. `pg_constraint`"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html).