# How to get the list of all constraints, their tables and their columns in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I want to get the list of all constraints, their tables and their columns, something like

```
constraint                    | table | columns
------------------------------|-------|---------------
table1_colum1_colum2_key       table1   {colum1, colum2}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: You could retrive that from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. Here example for Foreign Keys [Postgres: SQL to list table foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152260/postgres-sql-to-list-table-foreign-keys)

Comment: Which constraints are you referring to? Primary Key? Unique constraints? Check Constraints? Not null constraint? Foreign key constraints? Exclusion constraints?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name All constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constraints can be queried via `pg_constraint`. Tables are included in `pg_class` and columns in `pg_attributes`. Schemas are in `pg_namespace`.

Something like the following may work for you.

```
SELECT con.conname "constraint",
       concat(nsp.nspname, '.', rel.relname) "table",
       (SELECT array_agg(att.attname)
               FROM pg_attribute att
                    INNER JOIN unnest(con.conkey) unnest(conkey)
                               ON unnest.conkey = att.attnum
               WHERE att.attrelid = con.conrelid) "columns"
       FROM pg_constraint con
            INNER JOIN pg_class rel
                       ON rel.oid = con.conrelid
            INNER JOIN pg_namespace nsp
                       ON nsp.oid = rel.relnamespace;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.