# Can I use a sql query to get a list of all primary and foreign keys in a PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have a client using a PostgreSQL database.  I'm new to PostgreSQL and need a little help.  I need to get a list of primary and foreign keys from all the tables in the public schema.  There seems to be inconsistent data in the database.  I tried queries from other posts with no success.  When I look at the constraints on the table I can see the primary and foreign keys.  How can this same information using SQL?

[image: table]
[image: primary key properties]
[image: foreign key properties]

Comment: Look at the `information_schema` schema.  It is self-explanatory.

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1152321/5651972

Answer (score 1):

Using information_schema and restricting to `public` schema. **NOTE**: this will only display tables you have privileges on. So if you want to see everything you will need to do this as sufficiently privileged user.

```
SELECT
    constraint_schema,
    table_name,
    constraint_type,
    constraint_name
FROM
    information_schema.table_constraints
WHERE
    constraint_schema = 'public'
    AND constraint_type IN ('FOREIGN KEY', 'PRIMARY KEY')
ORDER BY
    table_name,
    constraint_type;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'll give it a try.