# Get all the column names having a Foreign Key contraint

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I am using the PostgreSQL. I want to write a query that returns all the column names having foreign key constraint and also the name of the table these columns they refer to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152260/postgres-sql-to-list-table-foreign-keys

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the `information_schema` views don't give you the column names, so you'll have to use the catalog:

```
SELECT c.conrelid::regclass AS source_table,
       a.attname AS column_name,
       k.n AS position,
       c.confrelid::regclass AS referenced_table
FROM pg_constraint AS c
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(c.conkey) WITH ORDINALITY AS k(attnum, n)
   JOIN pg_attribute AS a
      ON k.attnum = a.attnum AND c.conrelid = a.attrelid
WHERE c.contype = 'f'
ORDER BY c.conrelid::regclass::text, k.n;
```

To get the data for only a specific table, add the following to the `WHERE` condition:

```
AND c.conrelid = 'mytable'::regclass
```

Comment: Where do I put the name of the table for which I want to get the fk columns and the referenced tables? This query runs for all the tables in the current schema I think?

Comment: It is for all tables in all schemas, which is what you asked for. I have added a suggestion for an extra `WHERE` condition to my answer.